# Binding to vm breaks reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Extending controller binded to var `vm = this` fails to read binded values from component `bindings`

In example the difference is in (clicking the button displays entity)

```
app.controller('ThisBasicCtrl', function() {
  this.click = function() {
    this.text = this.entity;
  };
});
```

---

```
app.controller('VmBasicCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.click = function() {
    vm.text = vm.entity; // here entity is undefined
  };

  vm.clickThatWorks = function() {
    this.text = this.entity // 'NOT really VM but shows the value';
  }
});
```

---

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.entity = {
    name: 'test'
  };
});

app.controller('ThisBasicCtrl', function() {
  this.click = function() {
    this.text = this.entity;
  };
});

app.component('thisExtendedComponent', {
  template: '<button ng-click="vm.click()">This controller</button><div>{{vm.text}}</div>',
  controller: 'ExtendedCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  bindings: {
    entity: '<'
  }
});

app.controller('ExtendedCtrl', function($controller) {
  angular.extend(this, $controller('ThisBasicCtrl'));
});

app.controller('VmBasicCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.click = function() {
    vm.text = vm.entity; // here entity is undefined
  };

  vm.clickThatWorks = function() {
    this.text = this.entity // 'NOT really VM but shows the value';
  }
});

app.component('vmExtendedComponent', {
  template: '<button ng-click="vm.click()">VM controller</button><div>{{vm.text}}</div>',
  controller: 'VmExtendedCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  bindings: {
    entity: '<'
  }
});

app.controller('VmExtendedCtrl', function($controller) {
  angular.extend(this, $controller('VmBasicCtrl'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <div style="border: 1px solid;">
    <h5>
Extends <i style="color:orange">this</i> controller
</h5>
    <this-extended-component entity="vm.entity"></this-extended-component>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div style="border: 1px solid;">
    <h5>
Extends <i style="color:orange">VM</i> controller
</h5>
    <vm-extended-component entity="vm.entity"></vm-extended-component>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend will copy the referance in the function...

On your `thisExtendedComponent` component you are extending `ThisBasicCtrl` and its `click` function referancing ownself inside the function but
`vmExtendedComponent` component is extending `VmBasicCtrl` controller and inside of `click` function it is referancing `VmBasicCtrl` controller not ownself.

So when you run the function `vm` variable is `vmExtendedComponent`'s referance but variable changing in `VmBasicCtrl`.

***DEMONSTRATION***

In the example below there is a two component created with same controller. Controller has `click` and `clickThatWorks` functions. When you press the button component will log the `ctrl` variable on controller. The main difference is `click` func referancing a variable but `clickThatWorks` referancing ownself.

Run and see the result.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.entity = {
    name: 'test'
  };
});

app.controller('VmBasicCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.ctrl = 'vmbasic';
  vm.click = function() {
    console.log(vm.ctrl, vm.entity); // this is referancing vmBasic only
    vm.text = vm.entity; // here entity is undefined
  };

  vm.clickThatWorks = function() {
    console.log(this.ctrl, this.entity); // this is referancing ownself
    this.text = this.entity // 'NOT really VM but shows the value';
  }
});

app.component('vmExtendedComponent1', {
  template: '<span>click Example</span> <br><button ng-click="vm.click()">VM controller</button><div>{{vm.text}}</div>',
  controller: 'VmExtendedCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  bindings: {
    entity: '<'
  }
});

app.component('vmExtendedComponent2', {
  template: '<span>clickThatWorks Example </span><br><button ng-click="vm.clickThatWorks()">VM controller</button><div>{{vm.text}}</div>',
  controller: 'VmExtendedCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  bindings: {
    entity: '<'
  }
});

app.controller('VmExtendedCtrl', function($controller) {
  angular.extend(this, $controller('VmBasicCtrl'));
  this.ctrl = 'vmextended';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <vm-extended-component1 entity="vm.entity"></vm-extended-component1>
    <vm-extended-component2 entity="vm.entity"></vm-extended-component2>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a solution or a demonstration, please

Comment: You can see the referance problem in demonstration.

Comment: thank you for effort, can this behaveour be demonstrated/explained with plain javascript? has prototype something to do here? i'm trying to extend vm controller without rewriting it to 'this'. and i'm aware  i could use service, but again would have to rewrite a lot of code.

Comment: This is a logic problem. With usage of prototype or some other architecture even with an other language if you do the same thing you will face same result. You have your answer.